# When it runs 'Spark.sql' ,always shows 'WARN Hive: Failed to access metastore. This class should not accessed in runtime'

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When it runs 'Spark.sql' ,always shows 'WARN Hive: Failed to access metastore. This class should not accessed in runtime'

The detail is on the picture:
[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please avoid adding links as questions because the expectation is that the question stands alone even when the link is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable hive metastore in spark shell by setting the value of `spark.sql.catalogImplementation` to ***in-memory*** which is ***hive*** by default.

```
spark-shell --conf spark.sql.catalogImplementation=in-memory
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `Hive` as metastore, please remember to start it by:

`hive --service metastore`